# How to merge a child arrays based on a common field?

Tags: mule, dataweave, mulesoft

I have an input which has common field as an array of object, and I need to merge the object within same field.
**input Payload**:

```
{
  "ID": "102B0YT0",
  "line": [
    {
      "Number": 1,
      "quantityd": 18,
      "Shipped": 15
    }
  ],
  "line": [
    {
      "Number": 2,
      "quantity": 58,
      "Shipped": 8
    },
    {
      "lineNumber": 2,
      "quantity": 59,
      "Shipped": 9
    }
  ],
  "line": [
    {
      "lineNumber": 3,
      "Ordered": 11,
      "Shipped": 17
    }
  ]
}
```

I'm expecting below output where all the line object will be concatenated and merged under 1 line.
**Desired Output**:

```
{
  "ID": "102B0YT0",
  "line": [
    {
      "Number": 1,
      "quantityd": 18,
      "Shipped": 15
    },
    {
      "Number": 2,
      "quantity": 58,
      "Shipped": 8
    },
    {
      "lineNumber": 2,
      "quantity": 59,
      "Shipped": 9
    },
    {
      "lineNumber": 3,
      "Ordered": 11,
      "Shipped": 17
    }
  ]
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: Please use proper formatting to make your question more readable. You can use triple backtick " ``` " to wrap your code/json for proper formatting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `line` keys from the output then add a new `line` key with the values of each `line` then flatten it. The multi value selector `*.line` returns an array of the values of all `line` keys. Because each element is an array `flatten()` is needed to get the value of each sub-array in a single array.

```js
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
payload - "line" ++  (line: flatten(payload.*line))
```

Comment: really appreciate your enout, that sorted out the issue